# Which geothermal power plant type is most effecient?

Tags: geology, temperature, geothermal-heat

There are three geothermal systems that are commonly used: dry steam, flash steam, and binary cycle[<sup>[1]</sup>](https://www.eia.gov/energyexplained/index.cfm?page=geothermal_power_plants). What are the efficiencies of the plants from best to least efficient?

I did a moderate amount of research on all three systems, but the only thing that I found on Google is the efficiency of geothermal as a whole.  I could not find anything regarding the the efficiency of each individual one.

Comment: Welcome to EarthScience.SE. Please clarify: did you do some initial research on your own on these three types of systems?

Comment: I did a moderate amount of research on all three systems, but the only thing that I find on Google is the efficiency of geothermal overall. The question that I have is the effeciency of each individual one.

Comment: Are you asking about the thermal efficiency of economical efficiency e.g. kWh/$ ?

Comment: This question is not about earth science. It's about a technology that utilizes geothermal energy and the efficiency of such technology. It is off topic here. It is more appropriate to SE Engineering.

Comment: It could happily be migrated to [sustainability.se] or [engineering.se] : @HypnosStratagem just flag it for mod attention, and ask for a migration